# A distribution whose product distribution is standard normal

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid r.v. What is the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ s.t. $XY\sim N(0, 1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_k$ be iid r.v. If
$$X_i = \epsilon\cdot\exp\left\{\frac{\ln 2}{2k} - G_{1/k, 0} - \sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[\frac{G_{1/k, j}}{2j+1} - \frac 1{2k}\ln\left(1 + \frac 1 j\right)\right]\right\},$$
where $G_{1/k, 0}, G_{1/k, 1}, \ldots$ are iid $\text{Gamma}(1/k, 1)$ r.v.'s and $\epsilon$ is a Rademacher r.v. independent of $G_{1/k, 0}, G_{1/k, 1}, \ldots$, then [Pinelis (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09838v1) shows that $\prod_{i=1}^k X_i\sim N(0, 1)$.

For your special case $k=2$, we obtain:
$$X = \epsilon\cdot\exp\left\{\frac{\ln 2}{4} - G_{1/2, 0} - \sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[\frac{G_{1/2, j}}{2j+1} - \frac 1{4}\ln\left(1 + \frac 1 j\right)\right]\right\}, X\sim Y, XY\sim N(0, 1).$$

### Example

Although the definition contains an infinite sum, the elements of the sum approach zero as $j$ approaches infinity. Therefore, a finite sum may provide a good approximation in many applications. This is shown by the following Python code, which replaces $\infty$ by 100 and then plots the probability density functions of $X, Y,$ and $XY$ by drawing independent pseudo-random samples of size $10^7$ from the r.v.'s, multiplying the samples, and plotting three histograms:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pinelis(k, size, iterations=100):
    arange1 = np.arange(iterations) + 1
    def eps(): return (np.random.uniform(size=size) < 0.5) * 2.0 - 1.0
    def gamma(size): return np.random.gamma(1.0 / k, size=size)
    def rv():
        return eps() * np.exp(
            np.log(2.0) / (2.0 * k) - gamma(size) -
            np.sum(gamma((size, iterations)) / (2.0 * arange1 + 1.0), axis=-1) +
            np.sum(np.log(1.0 + 1.0 / arange1) / (2.0 * k))
        )
    return [rv() for _ in range(k)]

X, Y = pinelis(k=2, size=10**7)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 4), constrained_layout=True)
fig.suptitle('Random variable probability density functions')
for ax, s, variable in [(ax1, X, '$X$'), (ax2, Y, '$Y$'), (ax3, X * Y, '$XY$')]:
    ax.hist(s, 'auto', density=True)
    ax.set_title('Variable {}'.format(variable))
    ax.set_xlim(-1.96, 1.96)
    ax.set_xlabel('value')
    ax.set_ylabel('probability density')
    ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Empirical distributions of X, Y, and XY]

### Related Questions

In [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/199755) to [the question “Square root of normal distribution”](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199667/square-root-of-normal-distribution), [Iosif Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/users/36721/iosif-pinelis) formulated the theorem used in this answer. This is further discussed in [the question “Which distributions of $X$ and $Y$ yield a Gaussian $Z=XY$?”](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347992/which-distributions-of-x-and-y-yield-a-gaussian-z-xy/348000#348000), which is likely a duplicate of this question.